# Is my plan to bolster gate posts reasonable?

Tags: post

We have some gates made with lumber and thin cladding hanging on 3x2 lumber posts... one side house wall, other side 6ft post mounted to a 4ft concrete post.

We're building some new heavy duty gates and have underestimated the weight using 6x1 board.

The plan is to use materials already delivered: 75x75 post to house using 3x anchors from floor to 6ft.

On the other side we're using a thin steel post cover to make it look 6ft then was going to mount a 75x75 post to it with two anchors then a self tapping screw at top into post cover.

For extra support we're putting a 75x75 post across the top to stop the post side flexing.

Would this work or would the heavy gates likely rip off the posts?

Or could we mitigate in by using support wheels on the gates?

[image]

[image]

Comment: cls with no comment on what the heck it means to you, so...cold limp spaghetti? colorful live squid? catatonic limpid surfers? chain link supermagnets? Anyway,  take the [tour] and [edit] your question which is currently vague and opinion-based.

Comment: Canadian Lumber Size?

Comment: CLS is equivalent to N American spf (spruce pine fir), in other words, interior softwood. And to the OP, I haven’t the brain space to parse your issue, but the answer to heavy gates is almost always wheels.

Comment: May help avoid some confusion if you used imperial or metric units consistently.

Comment: I would positively adore some photos. While you may have provided all critical dimensions, a visual really helps gel understanding. I would avoid attaching anything to the house. In addition to causing siding penetrations and damage, it'll transmit sound throughout.